# Can't convert encrypted data in string format because "it is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to encrypt a text with the RSA algorithm and convert it in string format after the encryption.
Now, whilst the encrypted text in byte format is there, I'm not able to get it converted in string since there is an error of protection level.
I'm quite new with encryption systems and I don't know if the data need to be treated in some way in order to be copied/converted.
Could you please clarify me this matter?

This is the piece of code:

```
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    UnicodeEncoding encode = new UnicodeEncoding();

    RSAParameters PublicKey;
    RSAParameters PrivateKey;
    byte[] encBytes;
    string encString;

     // ********************* ENCRYPT THE TEXT WITH PUBLIC KEY *********************
    private void buttonEncrypt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        rsa.ImportParameters(PublicKey);

        encBytes = rsa.Encrypt(encode.GetBytes(textBoxIn.Text), false);
        encString = encode.GetString(encBytes);   <-- INACCESSIBLE DATA ERROR                  
        rsa.Dispose();
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05cts4c3%28v=vs.95%29)?

```
encString = encode.GetString(encBytes, 0, encBytes.Length);
```

Comment: However, I've applied the same method also to the decryption part of the program but, in that case, most of the times an exception is raised (unknown error 80007001), which seems due to the rsa algorithm itself rather than the code. Do you have any idea about this issue? Thanks anyway.